# Weird issue with asp.net ImageButton and javascript onmouseover to change image opacity

Tags: javascript, asp.net, opacity, imagebutton, onmouseover

I'm new to web development and have been searching around for this exact issue but haven't found any discussion yet. Basically I have an asp:ImageButton inside a repeater that I have created as below:

```
<asp:ImageButton onmouseover="MouseOverArr(this)" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#     Container.DataItem %>'/>
```

and the javascript function:

```
function MouseOverArr(image) {
    image.style.opacity = 0.75;
}
```

However, this code does NOT work. If I instead do: `onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0.75'"` then it works. Also, if I change the function to get the id first and then use `document.getElementById` to retrieve the element then set opacity on that element, all is good. Why would the original code above not work?

Comment: It works on IE and FF...with a png image I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, the code I posted actually worked. I have a stupid typo in my actual project that causes the problem. Can't believe I didn't notice it sooner but must have been a long day. Thanks for all the suggestions.